# Difference between directory and file paths for symlink and hardlink in Linux

Tags: files, directory, symbolic-link

I'm trying to define symlink and hardlinks between directories and files.

For example, I defined the path:

```
/mnt/data/d1/myp
```

And I wrote the command like that for symlink.

```
ln -s /etc/passwd /mnt/data/d1/myp
```

Here, myp should be a file.

Also, I defined a path for my directory.

```
/mnt/data/myd
```

And I wrote the command like that for symlink:

```
ln -s /mnt /mnt/data/myd
```

Here, myd should be a directory.

Link count:

```
12 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 sys sys     4 Jan  8 13:20 myd -> /mnt
```

My question is this: Should I write the paths of directories and files differently? Or should they be written the same? Is it correct that I did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to name symlinks to files and folders differently, unless it helps you organize your files. In short, there's nothing wrong with what you have done so far.